# Setting class variable value using self. versus classname

Tags: python

In python class (say class C) lets say we have class variable V = 0. Lets say this is a counter that keeps track of how many objects of the class have been created.

In the init methid, say we want to fetch the class variable value. We can do this either by writing C.V or self.V - assuming both do exactly the same thing.

To set the value of this class variable, there are same 2 options so what is the difference of using:

C.V += 1 versus self.V += 1

Is it that using self will update the variable at that object level and other objects wont get the change? Or do both approach behave the same.

Comment: _Is it that using self will update the variable at object level and other objects wont get the change?_  — Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting C.V refers to the class's definition. This will set the value for all objects of the same class. Using `self` refers to the current instance, or object, of that class. This will not affect other objects of the same class.

**EDIT** -- Credits to @Jdw136

And adding on to what @CalderWhite said, when you use a normal variable in a class (C.V), that variable is shared among all instances of that class. On the other hand when you use the self. Method (self.V), each instance of that object gets its own variable all to itself. Keeping this in mind, you can use this knowledge to avoid creating the same variable in the stack over and over.

Comment: @variable does my answer make sense?

Comment: And adding on to what @CalderWhite said, when you use a normal variable in a class (C.V), that variable is shared among all instances of that class. On the other hand when you use the self. Method (self.V), each instance of that object gets its own variable all to itself. Keeping this in mind, you can use this knowledge to avoid creating the same variable in the stack over and over.

Comment: Ok so if the task is to have the V count the number of instances of the class. Then the correct way is to write C.V+=1. Now lets say the instance wants to change this value in another method and not reflect to other instances then the right way is self.V=someValue. Right?

Comment: I thought that the only way to have local effect was using instance.V And didnt realise using self.V within the class will also have same effect.

Comment: Using self allows a class to reference its own instance. Do you have any other clarifications you need?